# Segmentation fault when using files in C++

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I have been trying a few IDEs for simple C++ school projects.
However, with codelite, anjuta and kdevelop I encountered a problem: when I am trying to read / write in files I get segmentation fault: core dumped.

I am using a basic source:

```
#include<stdio.h>

FILE*f=fopen("test.in","r");
FILE*g=fopen("test.out","w");

int main () {

    int a,b;
    fscanf(f,"%d %d",&a,&b);
    fprintf(g,"%d\n",a+b);

    fclose(f);
    fclose(g);

    return 0;
}
```

I have to say that programs with stdin/stdout work well.

Comment: You need to use a debugger and see where it faults and why. For example, if fopen fails, f or g might be null.

Comment: 1) use debugger. 2) check for errors.

Comment: Your code has no testing for error conditions and happily just blows right past them.

Comment: Why not open f and g within main?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? The code is C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - that was my first reaction, too, but it dynamically initializes `f` and `g`, which can't be done in C.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that the calls to `fopen` are not succeeding, perhaps because your program isn't being run from the same directory that contains the files. In that case, the pointers `f` and `g` will be null, and you must check for that before passing them to any C library functions.

You also need to check whether `fscanf` succeeded, otherwise using `a` and `b` will result in undefined behaviour (although that will most likely just cause the program to output garbage rather than crash).

You might be better off using `std::fstream` from the C++ library; but even then, you'll need to check whether the file streams were opened and the input read successfully.